# Different technologies to interact with SharePoint and External systems inside our SPFx web part

Tags: development, spfx, pnpjs, sphttpclient

I am developing 2 SPFx web parts. one which shows items from a SharePoint list and the other shows items assigned for the login user from SLACK.

now for the technologies, to connect to the SharePoint list and to the external systems i have those:-

1. To connect to SharePoint list:-

- SPHttpClient
- Raw jQuery
- PnP/PnPjs

2. To connect to Exernal API/system:-

- HttpClient
- Raw jQuery

now for SharePoint i usually use PnP/PnPjs because it ease the development compared to SPHttpClient & Raw jQuery + i use HttpClient to connect to external API because it is easier compared to Raw jquery.

but i am working with a client and they do not allow us to use any open source technologies not managed by Microsoft.so this mean i can not use PnP/PnPjs.. so is the alternative to use SPHttpCleint for internal and HttpClient of external for this customer?

Answer (score 0):

SPFx & SharePoint uses open-source components in it, the Fluent UI!

That's the same scenario I was facing earlier with one of my clients where they can't accept the fact that Microsoft is now open source. I guess most of Microsoft products are from open source, although not exactly 100%. From Windows, SharePoint, Azure AD website, Power Apps, Power Automate, literally almost everything. Even jQuery is also free & open source.

If that's the case, you only left with the legacy SpHttpClient, or fetch (for javascript) leveraging on purely SharePoint REST API. Please take note that Microsoft no longer adding features to SharePoint REST API and legacy SharePoint SOAP web service. It's now moving to Graph API.

Else you could convince them, I'm sure unknowingly in the past/existing projects they leveraged on open-source components.

https://opensource.microsoft.com/